# Python 2.7 How can I access objects created by one class from a list stored within a different class

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, class, inheritance

I'm trying to create a class User that stores certain attributes about a user, and another class User_Review that has a list of the objects/instances created by class User.

```
class User(object):
    user_objects = []
    def __init__(self, name, age)
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        User.user_objects.append(self)

class User_Review(User):
    user_list = # here is where I want user_objects to exist

user1 = User('leila', 23)
user2 = User('carter', 43)

# so user_list = [user1, user2]
```

To answer zondo and juanpa.arrivillaga, the purpose of User is to create objects with basic information, and User_Review is a method where I'd like to be able to do things with the list of users through other methods in the User_Review class, such as have methods that adds/removes users to the end of the user list, or display certain information (name only, for example).

Comment: You could do `user_list = User.user_objects`, but why do you want two references to the same thing?

Comment: Why is `User_Review` deriving from `User`? Why use a custom class at all, and not just use a `list`???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your purposes, I think you could instead of creating both the `user_objects` and `user_list` lists inside the classes, just retain the one inside `User_Review` (since you want their references to be stored in another class), and get rid of the one inside `User`, while simultaneously appending the created `User` object to the `user_list` from inside the `__init__` method rather than `user_objects`.

In practice, this would look something like the following.

```
class User(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        User_Review.user_list.append(self)

class User_Review(object):
    user_list = []

user1 = User('leila', 23)
user2 = User('carter', 43)
```

Printing out the name of the first user using `print(User_Review.user_list[0].name)` correctly outputs `carter`.

---

This approach, however, seems fairly counter intuitive:

- The `User_Review` class inherits `User` which to me does not make any logical sense, since you would not want to have a method such as `change_age` in `User_Review` if it happened to be implemented in `User`. You would however, want to be able to access the data inside each `User` object, which can be accomplished by just accessing the required `User` inside the list.
- As it stands, `User_Review` serves no real purpose, exactly the same thing could be achieved by just a regular list; however, if there are plans for implementing methods that rely on data from multiple or all `User` objects created, then this might be a viable solution.

Other solutions to this problem could be creating the list inside the `User` class only, and just using `User_Review` to access that list and do the required actions. Or more complexly creating a separate class from these two dedicated to storing, organizing, and retrieving users to and from a database.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation! I have a much better understanding of how these two classes interrelate, and now realize that `User_Review` does not need to inherit `User` which makes things much simpler.

Comment: Wonderful! I'd suggest reading up a bit more on object-oriented programming to get yourself familiar with inheritance and how objects and other non-primitive values are stored in memory, in addition you could come across other useful stuff to learn about like polymorphism and encapsulation and all those other fancy words which will be required to develop any kind of usable system in the future. Good luck!